# Information is not being written into file in append mode

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer in python and my lecturer wants us to make a program from scratch specifically w hard code.

It was running well previously, but when I tried testing the program earlier, this part of the program started to run an error. It said it cannot run code on a closed file. Can anyone help point out where the problem is?

Thank you so much

```
def temporder():
    allmenu = open("allmenu.txt","r") 
    temporder = open("neworder.txt","a") 
    entry = str.upper(input("Please enter a valid product code: "))
    for lines in allmenu: 
        code,price = lines.split(",") 
        if (entry in code): 
            temporder.write("\n" + code + "," + price)
            temporder.close() 
            allmenu.close()
```

Comment: On the very first loop iteration where `entry in code` is true, you close both files. Is that what you meant to do, or did you mean to unindent those so hey run at the _end_ of the function?

Comment: You should use `with open()` to open files so you don't forget to close them.

Comment: As the answer to the linked duplicate says, it's an error to do anything to a closed file other than try to close it again. Once it's closed, you can't write to it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indented the last 2 lines `temporder.close()` and `allmenu.close()`, this means that the first time it executes the if condition, it closes both files. Put the last 2 lines in the same indent level as the `for` loop and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move file close statements (`file.close()`) to outside the `for` loop. Your code checks the first line of allmenu file and then closes the file.